# Problems with implementing custom actionbar android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I've created a custom action bar layout below. I want to implement this for one of my activities (the aim is to have it for all the activities but I'm testing with one for now). I use the following code to do this:

```html
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_all_bets);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View customView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customView);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

However, instead of getting the actionbar, I get a mashup of things looking like this which doesn't even fill the full width of the screen. [image]

action_bar.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:background="#27044A"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#d35400"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="User"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#d35400"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="tester@tester.com"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#d35400"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Coins"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#d35400"
                android:text="60000"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#d35400"
                android:text="Winnings"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColor="#d35400"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="35000"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
                android:text="Logout"
                android:textColor="#ffd35400"
                android:textSize="13sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="85"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="100">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/football50"
                android:layout_weight="93"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#d35400"
                android:text= "Bet Now!"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="100">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src = "@drawable/chip50"
                android:layout_weight="93"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text = "My Bets"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#d35400"
                android:layout_weight="7"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="100">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/clover50"
                android:layout_weight="93"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text = "Coin Frenzy"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#d35400"
                android:layout_weight="7"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="100">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/trophy50"
                android:layout_weight="93"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text = "Rankings"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#d35400"
                android:layout_weight="7"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:weightSum="100">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/moneybag50"
                android:layout_weight="93"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Shop"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#d35400"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="7"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]
Intended look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by it not filling the width of the screen? The mashup is because you're trying to squeeze so many nested LinearLayouts and things together into one ActionBar. The three dots on the right is the overflow menu (which you can disable).

Check out the [Android design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-toolbars) for proper uses of the Toolbar (since ActionBar is deprecated). I think that you have more of a design issue than a programming issue.

Comment: The thing is in the design preview it looks perfectly fine. All I need is one layout on top which shows the 3 parameters and the logout button and the 4 other layouts are meant to be tabs for the actionbar to navigate through my activities

Comment: What I'm trying to create is basically the actionbar from the contacts or phone app on android with one additional tab and one linear layout above it showing information

Comment: Can you post a screenshot for what you're trying to make it look like (like from the preview or from the contacts app you're referring to)?

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're trying to do now. Instead of using a ActionBar, you would be better suited to using a fragment inflated with this layout. Then, you can just swap out fragments for the main things you want to display below

Comment: Can you provide me with a link or some short guidance on how I would do this with this xml file...I never worked with fragments before tbh

Comment: Ok, your first step should be reading up on the difference between Fragments and Activities then. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

I would recommend opening up an empty project in Android Studio with a Navigation Drawer. You can see how they exchange fragments when different things are clicked in the drawer. It'll be the same sort of idea with your app, except you're replacing the fragment that's below the fragment that you've shown me (in the screenshot).

Comment: Alright, I watched some youtube videos and added the two fragments to the two activities representing the first two tabs. My next concern is how to make the fragment usable so that when I click on the Bet Now tab for example, some code is executed. I know how to do this with buttons, but with linearlayouts I'm not sure, do I have to implement a listener or something of that sort?

Comment: Yes, an onClickListener

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to add lot of views in the action bar.Usually the action bar layout is simple and clean.Mostly the action bar purpose is to show important updates and navigational views.
If you still need this GUI, I think you can discard this action bar GUI and instead create reusable custom layout and place it on top of every activity.

Comment: How would I make sure its on top of every activity?